# display counter notification in icon launcher android

Tags: android

In my android application i want to display the count icon badge. i'm using the code from [enter link description here](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger).when i test it i always get this error. `unable the execute badge.shortcutbadger is currently not support the home launcher package"com.android.launcher"`. when i debug it i find that the application dosn't get correctly the package name.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    ResolveInfo resolveInfo = getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    String currentHomePackage = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
   //String currentHomePackage = "me.leolin.shortcutbadger.example.MainActivity";
    TextView textViewHomePackage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewHomePackage);
    textViewHomePackage.setText("launcher:" + currentHomePackage);
```

so i put it manually but i always get the same message error with the correct package name.

Answer (score 0):

The library you're using only works with the default Samsung, HTC, LG, Sony and other launchers, but not the official Android launcher (`com.android.launcher`).

That's probably why you're having issues testing your app.

Comment: sorry but i didn't understand this sentence. what does it mean about the deafult launcher? i'm testing it with saumsung real device. how to make it work. thank you

Comment: Can you post a picture of your launcher/home screen of your test device on http://imgur.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the badge count for the launcher icon using the following code, but this feature is not supported for all the devices it supported on the devices like Samsung, HTC etc...

```
 public static void setBadge(Context context, int count) {
        String launcherClassName = getLauncherClassName(context);
        if (launcherClassName == null) {
            return;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.BADGE_COUNT_UPDATE");
        intent.putExtra("badge_count", count);
        intent.putExtra("badge_count_package_name", context.getPackageName());
        intent.putExtra("badge_count_class_name", launcherClassName);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

public static String getLauncherClassName(Context context) {

    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolveInfos) {
        String pkgName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName;
        if (pkgName.equalsIgnoreCase(context.getPackageName())) {
            String className = resolveInfo.activityInfo.name;
            return className;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. where should i put this code. in the main activity? because my application has a splashscreen and i'm using navigation drawer

Comment: thank you i will try it and keep you in touch. but i have another question. shoud i use the shortcutbadger librairy or it's working without it?